# What is difference between loprox and antifungal cream?

Tags: medications, prescription

To get loprox ([cicloprox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ciclopirox)), you need a doctors prescription. It's used to cure fungal infections.

But you can buy some antifungal creams without prescriptions.

Can't you just replace one with another?

Or does loprox have some features, which are absent in other antifungal creams?

Comment: there are tons of anti fungics, as well as there are tons of antibiotics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets start with the concept of **what is Anti-fungal** medication **"Antifungal medicines are used to treat fungal infections, which are most commonly found on the skin, hair and nails."**[NHS](http://www.nhs.uk/Conditions/Antifungal-drugs/Pages/Introduction.aspx) 
As you see Antifungals are medications that **used to treat or prevent mycoses** ( fungal infection) which divided in two major groups fungicides and fungistatics.

**Loprex (ciclopirox)** is a synthetic FDA approved antifungal agent used mostly for treating  superficial mycoses and yeast infections of the skin, such as athlete's foot, jock itch, and ringworm it works by stopping or killing fungus but if you If you suffer from any adverse reaction to medication report it to your doctor. [2](http://reference.medscape.com/drugs/antifungals-topical) [3](https://www.drugs.com/mtm/ciclopirox-topical.html) [4](http://www.accessdata.fda.gov/scripts/cder/drugsatfda/index.cfm?fuseaction=Search.Overview&DrugName=CICLOPIROX)

We have lots of different mycoses conditions like athlete's foot, ringworm, candidiasis which are less severe or more serious conditions like Cryptococcosis, meningitis etc [5](http://www.webmd.com/drugs/2/drug-61279/antifungal-cream-topical/details/list-conditions) **as you see we have different kind of conditions which made by different kinds of microorganisms so as a result we have wide range of medications that each is suitable for specific conditions and indications .** here you can see some of the other [topical Antifungal agents](http://reference.medscape.com/drugs/antifungals-topical) that are available in market.

**Based on condition,indications and guidelines your doctor or professional health care chooses and prescribes the medication so you can you can not just replace it** even in some cases with a generic version **without consulting your doctor**.

**As i know yes we have few OTC Antifungals but it differs from a country to another.** check [here](http://www.pharmacytimes.com/publications/issue/2012/may2012/combating-fungal-skin-infections) for more information.

For more information checkout [medlineplus.gov](https://medlineplus.gov/druginfo/meds/a604021.html) and [Webmd](http://www.webmd.com/drugs/2/drug-61279/antifungal-cream-topical/details/list-conditions).

Comment: I haven't been happy with how difficult it was to remove an infection with sprays and I have read that they have serious side-effects. I have personally successfully removed a fungal infection from my own hand by spraying apple cider vinegar on the area and scrubbing the area with an old toothbrush. A stiffer, larger brush would have been better, I think but it was what I had handy. The fungi are just on the surface and in the cracks so physically removing them (if you have access) just takes a few seconds.